# append 2d time series array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf

I have yearly time series data in different 10 NETCDF file. Shape of file is:

```
value.shape = 

(365, 310, 250)
```

I tried to make a array with shape of something like:

```
(3650, 310,250)
```

by appending yearly data in to it. I used this function but did not worked:

```
files = glob.glob('/home/user/data/*.nc')    
time_series = np.array([[]])
    for i in files:
        yearly = Dataset(i,'r')
        value = yearly.variables['AOD'][:,:,:]
        time_series = np.append(time_series,value)
```

any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: *did not worked* - so what happens instead?

Comment: i got this shape: time_series.shape = (442912500,)

Comment: [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) "If `axis` is not specified, values can be any shape **and will be flattened before use**."

Comment: While doing:  time_series = np.append(time_series,value,axis = 0), I got this error:  all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would change your code:

```
def make_array(loc, shape = (365, 31, 25)):  
    # loc is string, can have any number of files, can change shape of data
    files = glob.glob(str(loc) + '/*.nc')    
    time_series = np.empty((len(files),) + shape) # create an extra dimension for files, 'np.empty' doesn't waste time initializing
    for i, j in enumerate(files): # enumerate gives you indices
        yearly = Dataset(j, 'r')
        time_series[i] = yearly.variables['AOD'][:, :, :]
    return time_series.reshape(*((-1,) + shape[1:])) # -1 allows size to change
```

Comment: One of the key benefits of `numpy` is its ability to keep track of many dimensions.  It's almost always easier and clearer to construct arrays with more dimensions and then reshape/index/mask/stride down to what you need.  Trying to jump straight to the data formats required for follow-on functions is almost always a case of [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of the merged array at the start, it is much easier to create a Numpy array of the correct size. For example (I reduced the dimensions a bit..):

```
import numpy as np

merged_values = np.empty((3650, 31, 25))

for i in range(10):
    value = np.random.random((365, 31, 25))
    merged_values[i*365:(i+1)*365] = value
```

Comment: As a side note; in terms of performance it greatly differs from problem to problem, but in my experience, starting with a correctly sized array and filling that is often much faster than using `np.append` or `list.append`

Comment: A bit more clear and extensible to build a `(n, 365, 31, 25)` array and then do `reshape(-1,31,25)`.

Comment: That is indeed an elegant solution (I tried it), but I'm not sure how/why the `reshape(-1,...)` works?

Comment: `reshape(-1, . . .)`means calculate that dimension's size with respect to the original size divided by the product of the other dimension sizes. In this case, it will be 442912500/(25*31) = 3650 = 365*10, but if you have more or less files it will be different.

Comment: @DanielF reshape (-1,310,250) also works for me. Thank you for your help.